# How to console.log multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, css, function

I am creating a javascript exercise, my idea was to create a function that would give me an icon return, I am using FontAwesome for this. I managed to make it show the icon and the message but I wanted to add my predefined styles for titles, emphasis .. etc through a function but I still can't think of a form. I even tried using Swith but it only copies css as any string

```js
function icones(ico_name, text,style ){ // Capture icon name, style to be used and text
    switch(ico_name) { //Check argument icon
        case 'user':
            ico_name = '%c ' //Icon will only be displayed after CSS declaration
            font = 'font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; font-size: 20px; content: "\f434";'
        break
    }  
    switch(style) { // Styling text
        case 'title':
            text = 'color: red'
        break
    }
    console.log(ico_name,font,text) 
}
icones('user','player', 'title') //Applying values to function
```

[image]

Comment: Here, read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: @Wolfeius However I haven't learned how to use DOM, I'm starting in javascript and I would like to use only css in the console, which is what I learned

Comment: What you are doing just returns a string.  To change the style you habe to access the property style and new style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use `document.getElementById()` to get an element in the webpage and then apply CSS styles.

For instance, if the element whose font you are trying to change has its `id` attribute set to `"changeMyFont"`:

```html
<span id="changeMyFont"></span>
```

you can change its CSS attributes using JavaScript as such:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("changeMyFont");
elem.style.fontFamily = "Font Awesome 5 Free";
elem.style.fontWeight = 900;
elem.style.fontSize = "20px";
```

To change the text color to red for a certain element, you can follow the same procedure.  To change the content within a HTML tag, use `innerHTML` (**do not allow user input here; it is an XSS threat**):

```js
document.getElementById("elementToChange").innerHTML = "HTML here";
```

You can use an HTML escape in there.

Comment: why don't use use `textContent`? `innerHTML` is a big performance loss if you only want to change some text.

Comment: As I said, it would really be easier to use the DOM to change, but I haven't gotten to this lesson yet, I want to use what I have learned so far using only javascript and CSS in the console.

Comment: @luismatheus I think you misunderstand something. You cannot do this stuff without touching the DOM or at least its core functionality. You cannot even add CSS to something without using "DOM functionality". You need a proper element ad access its style attribute otherwise all you have is a string which will not help you to show the icon. On top of that, please don't wait until your teacher or whatever comes and pokes you with a stick, before you learn new things. You should be learning all the time and all over the place, the subjects that currently matter and are of use for you.

Comment: @TheFool Thanks for the advice, I'm learning on my own, just wanted to add this challenge to me

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few hours between trial and error I was able to accomplish my feat.
The "secret" was to put 2 styles in just one console.log, the code may seem like a confusing drift and surely to improve it.

```js
function icones(ico_nome,texto,style ){ // Captura o nome do icone, o estilo que sera utilizado e o texto
    switch(ico_nome) { // Check argument icon
        case 'user':
            ico_nome = '%c ' // Icon will only be displayed after CSS declaration
            font_icon = 'font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; font-size: 20px;' //Declara a fonte para visualização
        break
    }  
    switch(style) { // Styling text
        case 'titulo': // Set styles for titles
            font_icon += 'color:red;' //Set the color Red to Icon
            style_text = 'color:blue; font-family: Arial;' // Set styles for texts
        break
        default: 
            font_icon += 'color: black' // Set default color
    }
    console.log(ico_nome + ' ' + '%c' + texto,font_icon,style_text)  //Join the 2 styles and reveal the output
}
icones('user','Usuario', 'titulo') //Applying values to function
```

Final result
 ---- [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNgdL.png)
Still do not know how to insert the image directly into the post sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery function `.css()` For example:

```
$("#element").css("font-size", "20pt")
```

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to suggest jQuery to anyone really but especially to beginners. He wants to learn "proper" js. The question also does not mention jQuery so it would be some random dependency no one wants.